# std::thread with SFML on Linux

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, multithreading, c++11

I tried porting my SFML Project, I developed in Visual Studio on my PC, to my Linux with Eclipse. Finally everything works fine, except for std::thread. I just use this for a simple render Thread and the code works in Visual Studio on Windows. But when I try to run the Code:


`std::thread renderThread(render);`


on Linux in Eclipse, there is a Error:

> [xcb] Unknown request in queue while dequeuing
>   [xcb] Most likely this is a multi-threaded client and XInitThreads has not been called
>   [xcb] Aborting, sorry about that.

And even if I add a "XInitThreads()" call before creating the Thread, the same error message shows up a few seconds after starting.

I already linked the pthread library and added "-pthread" to the compiler options.


Thanks in advance for all advices and every kind of help.



**Edit:**


Code Snippet:

```
XInitThreads();

sf::ContextSettings settings;
settings.depthBits = 32;
settings.stencilBits = 32;
window.create(sf::VideoMode(1120, 630), "TITLE", sf::Style::Default, settings);
window.setVerticalSyncEnabled(true);
window.clear(COLOR);
window.display();
initStartup();  //loading Resources (.png, font...)
startscreen->phaseStarted = myClock.getElapsedTime().asMilliseconds();

window.setActive(false);

sf::Thread renderThread(render);
renderThread.launch();`
```

**Edit 2:**


I commented out my event handling loop `while (window.pollEvent(event)) {`

and one `sf::Mouse::getPosition(window)` call


And the error is gone.

Comment: what GUI library do you use? Looks like it calls some Xlib functions before you call XInitThreads(). http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/display/XInitThreads.html - XInitThreads should be first Xlib function to call

Comment: Which compiler and which version are you using ? Another solution could be using sf::Thread instead of std::thread.

Comment: I use the G++ compiler. I first tried it with sf::Thread and it didn't work either.

Comment: I don't use any Xlib calls directly. But I don't know if SFML is calling Xlib functions.

Comment: Maybe that link could help you : http://en.sfml-dev.org/forums/index.php?topic=6418.15

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, but this didn't really help. I already am including <X11/Xlib.h> and calling XInitThreads() but it doesn't help for me. I keep getting the same error message.

Comment: If calling `XInitThreads()` in the beginning of `int main()` doesn't help, then you might want to provide a complete and minimal code, so we actually see what you're doing. Also unless you know a lot, and I mean a lot, about parallel programming/concurrency, you'll most likely do more harm than good, in trying to decouple updating and rendering.

Comment: I set up a new Project trying to simplify the problem. And so I only created a `sf::Window` an `sf::Thread` and there was no problem, so I will have to look at what function causes the error message.